# Where should philosophy-of-language questions go?

Tags: discussion

Both [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/tags/philosophy-of-language/info) and [Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tags/philosophy-of-language/info) have <kbd>philosophy-of-language</kbd> tags with a decent number of questions (36 on Philosophy and 13 on Linguistics; the Linguistics site also has some related questions in other tags).

Should we recommend a site for where these sorts of questions should go? If so, which?

Comment: I don't know...I feel they are appropriate in both or either. I have no preference. I'd say just keep them wherever they appear?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Cerberus but this doesn't mean both are OK on both sites: tailor the question to the site you're (=general) posting it. We don't have the same kind of "investigation" and answers that Philosophy SE does. So the question should aim at a different target and get a different answer/analysis.

Other than that, posting on either is fine. Overlapping is impossible to avoid between sites and is not a reason for "forbidding" questions. Are they good for us? Then you can ask.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Alenanno's answer, I would say that the following rough criteria should apply:

- On **Linguistics**: questions dealing with the philosophical foundations for the study of languages. The [highest voted one](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1549/why-do-we-have-interest-in-dying-language-preservation) on the tag is a good example.
- On **Philosophy**:  questions dealing with the nature of language itself, or with how other philosophers tackled such problems. Again, the [highest voted question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/178/what-are-some-ways-to-read-wittgensteins-tractatus-other-than-resolute-irresolu) serves as a reference.

But, of course, the division is sometimes blurry, so use this as a guideline.

Comment: Not only are the types of questions different, but the methodology and references used to answer the questions is also different!

Comment: For those who have trouble telling the difference, here are some [Guidelines by Jim McCawley](http://specgram.com/SoLP/17.mccawley.untitled.html).